# Build Error: Using Soomla Plugin for ios In-App Purchase using Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I'm getting the following error while trying to build project in unity3d for ios in macbook.

Win32Exception: ApplicationName='python2.6', CommandLine='"/Users/subashchandra/SoomlaTutorialExample/Assets/Soomla/Editor/build-tools/Soomla_StoreRunner.py" "/Users/subashchandra/Desktop/SoomlaTutorialExample"', CurrentDirectory=''
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
PostProcessScriptStarter.OnPostprocessBuild (BuildTarget target, System.String pathToBuiltProject) (at Assets/Soomla/Editor/SoomlaPostBuild.cs:27)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
Uploading Screenshot 2014-09-08 15.04.44.jpg . . .

I don't understand the error at all. I followed a online tutorial, its working fine for the guy in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

They expect you to build on a IOS device which has python on it installed by default.

More info: https://github.com/soomla/unity3d-store/issues/339